# The variance of a simple estimate of the number of triangles

Tags: probability

Consider an undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $t$ triangles.  A triangle is a set of 3 vertices such that any two of them are connected by an edge of the graph.  In the streaming model we don't see the whole graph at once but instead one edge arrives at a time in arbitrary order and after an edges arrives we would like to be able to give an estimate for the number of triangles in the graph.  I am trying to understand the following simple method:

1. Randomly pick (uniformly with replacement) $k$ subsets $S_1, \dots, S_k$ of the vertices each of size $3$.
2. Let $x_S$ be the number of edges seen between the vertices in set $S$.
3. Let $c$ be the number of indices $i$ for which $x_{S_i}=3$. That is the number of triangles found.
4. Our estimate is $R = \frac{{n \choose 3}}{k}c$.

I  can see that $\mathbb{E}(R) = t$ (although a short clean proof would be wonderful). But what is $var(R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $C_i$ be the indicator of a triangle is formed in the sample subset $S_i$. Sine each subset is uniformly sampled, then

$$ C_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( \frac {t} { \binom {n} {3} } \right) $$
And
$$ C = \sum_{i=1}^k C_i $$

Therefore
$$ E[R] = \binom {n} {3} \frac {1} {k} E[C] 
= \binom {n} {3} \frac {1} {k}
\times k  \frac {t} {\binom {n} {3}} = t $$

So $R$ is an unbiased estimator of $t$ as claimed.

Next, since we are sampling with replacement, then $C_i$ are mutually independent. As a result

$$ \begin{align} Var[R] 
&= \binom {n} {3}^2 \frac {1} {k^2} Var[C] \\
&= \binom {n} {3}^2 \frac {1} {k^2} \sum_{i=1}^k Var[C_i] \\
&= \binom {n} {3}^2 \frac {1} {k^2} k \frac {t} {\binom {n} {3}} \left(1 - \frac {t} {\binom {n} {3}}\right) \\
&= \frac {t} {k} \left( \binom {n} {3} - t\right) \end{align} $$

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you